# how to create a file with the cmd?

Tags: git, powershell, github, cmd

I have a win7 machine and I use Git Shell (which seems to be Windows Powershell)

I am trying to follow the Lab 3 tutorial of GIT IMMERSION (`http://gitimmersion.com/lab_03.html`).

I do not know how to  `create a file named hello.rb with the contents below.`

```
puts "Hello, World"
```

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, can't you just paste that line into Notepad and save the file in the appropriate place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's Powershell, then use `Set-Content`

```
Set-Content hello.rb 'puts "Hello, World"'
```

Comment: How is this the correct answer? It doesn't work in the git shell.

Comment: @Swonkie The "Git Shell" for provided by GitHub for Windows is [configurable](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/05/21/introducing-github-for-windows.aspx/) to use the shell of your choice. The OP indicated it was probably Powershell, so that is what I used for the answer.

Comment: Ah I see. Didn't know about the version from GitHub. I still prefer my solution, since it works in pretty much any shell (even PowerShell).

Comment: @Swonkie Git Shell is configurable to use Git Bash, but the default shell is Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

The Git Shell is bash, not PowerShell.

```
echo 'puts "Hello, World"' > hello.rb
```

Comment: You need to remove the single quotes. That's not what he wanted :)

Comment: Yes, they are required - they won't end up in the file.

Comment: It's not clear that it is bash. If you install GitHub for Windows, for example, it creates a "Git Shell" link which is powershell with git commands added to your path.

Comment: It says "Git Bash" in the title of the window when I open git shell on my Windows 7 machine. The value of $BASH_VERSION is 3.1.0(1)-release