# How do I edit a text file in Git Bash?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I am using Windows 10 and am on Lab 5 of the Git Immersion tutorial, with Git Bash as my shell.

I've used `echo 'puts "Hello, World"' > hello.rb` to create the hello.rb file per the following:
[how to create a file with the cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984640/how-to-create-a-file-with-the-cmd)

I am to `change our hello program to take an argument from the command line. Change the file to be:`

```
puts "Hello, #{ARGV.first}!"
```

I've thought of using Sublime Text to edit the file, but I feel compelled to use Git Bash. How could I edit the file in Git Bash?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you feel compelled to use Git Bash? Sublime Text sounds to me like the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Haoyu: You want to edit a file without using a text editor???? When you are in the mood to punish yourself, there are plenty of well-tried methods....

Comment: @user1934428 Would it be possible to edit with a text editor such as emacs in Git Bash? I know it works for commit comments.

Comment: I have never thought that people might want to use anything else than a text editor. I'm just wandering: How did you edit your programs before? And why is this related to what shell you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GNU `sed` to substitute text.

`sed -i "s/World/#{ARGV.first}\!/" hello.rb`

```
cat hello.rb  
puts "Hello, #{ARGV.first}!
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command

edit: Or use a command line editor such as `vi` or `vim`.

Answer (score 4):

> The best way for me to edit a file in Git Bash is the command 'nano fileName.txt'. This command opens editing mode. After having your work done, press Ctrl + x. Then approve changes with "y" to finally exit nano.